# How to run webapp2(appengine) in Heroku?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, webapp2

Here is my project file

Procfile

```
web: python main.py
```

requirement.txt

```
webapp2==2.3
```

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("hello")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

still heroku give out a Application Error

what's wrong with my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base on their getting started with python it seems like you need gunicorn web server. Try adding gunicorn in your requirements.txt and procfile web: gunicorn main:app

Forgot to add the link:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

Also here is my webapp2-starter, it's setup to act like an appengine dev server but works outside app engine.
https://github.com/faisalraja/webapp2-starter